# Usage for CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech and long files

Tags: c#, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

In the speech sample apps, there's an example of CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput, however that returns after the first utterance.  I did notice that you can call RecognizeAsync multiple times, but there are a couple of odd behaviours with it:

1. I'm getting RecognitionErrorRaised fired with a "NoMatch" error in the middle of the file.
2. FinalResultsReceived is being fired with an empty result if there's a period of silence in the file.
3. There doesn't seem to be a consistent/trackable EOF event for recognition completion.

If I want to transcribe, say, a 20 minute audio file, is there a better way to do so with the unified speech SDK?  The same files were OK under the old Oxford package.  Ideally I'd like to be able to get time offsets of utterances as well as transcriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`StartContinuousRecognitionAsync ();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer.startcontinuousrecognitionasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [`StopContinuousRecognitionAsync ();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer.stopcontinuousrecognitionasync?view=azure-dotnet#applies-to) with the SDK to start and stop recognition.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/blob/master/documentation-samples/tutorial-speech-intent-recognition/csharp/speech_recognition_samples.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace MicrosoftSpeechSDKSamples
{
    public class SpeechRecognitionSamples
    {
        // Speech recognition from microphone.
        public static async Task RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync()
        {
            // <recognitionWithMicrophone>
            // Creates an instance of a speech factory with specified
            // subscription key and service region. Replace with your own subscription key
            // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("59a0243e86ae4919aa26f9e839f34b28", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input. The default language is "en-us".
            using (var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizer())
            {
                // Starts recognizing.
                Console.WriteLine("Say something...");

                // Starts recognition. It returns when the first utterance has been recognized.
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Checks result.
                if (result.RecognitionStatus != RecognitionStatus.Recognized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"There was an error. Status:{result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, Reason:{result.RecognitionFailureReason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.RecognizedText}");
                }
            }
            // </recognitionWithMicrophone>
        }

        // Speech recognition in the specified spoken language.
        public static async Task RecognitionWithLanguageAsync()
        {
            // <recognitionWithLanguage>
            // Creates an instance of a speech factory with specified
            // subscription key and service region. Replace with your own subscription key
            // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("59a0243e86ae4919aa26f9e839f34b28", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer for the specified language, using microphone as audio input.
            var lang = "en-us";
            using (var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizer(lang))
            {
                // Starts recognizing.
                Console.WriteLine($"Say something in {lang} ...");

                // Starts recognition. It returns when the first utterance has been recognized.
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Checks result.
                if (result.RecognitionStatus != RecognitionStatus.Recognized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"There was an error. Status:{result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, Reason:{result.RecognitionFailureReason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.RecognizedText}");
                }
            }
            // </recognitionWithLanguage>
        }
        // Speech recognition from file.
        public static async Task RecognitionWithFileAsync()
        {
            // <recognitionFromFile>
            // Creates an instance of a speech factory with specified
            // subscription key and service region. Replace with your own subscription key
            // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("59a0243e86ae4919aa26f9e839f34b28", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer using file as audio input.
            // Replace with your own audio file name.
            using (var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput(@"YourAudioFile.wav"))
            {
                // Starts recognition. It returns when the first utterance is recognized.
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Checks result.
                if (result.RecognitionStatus != RecognitionStatus.Recognized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"There was an error. Status:{result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, Reason:{result.RecognitionFailureReason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.RecognizedText}");
                }
            }
            // </recognitionFromFile>
        }

        // <recognitionCustomized>
        // Speech recognition using a customized model.
        public static async Task RecognitionUsingCustomizedModelAsync()
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech factory with specified
            // subscription key and service region. Replace with your own subscription key
            // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("59a0243e86ae4919aa26f9e839f34b28", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input.
            using (var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizer())
            {
                // Replace with the CRIS deployment id of your customized model.
                recognizer.DeploymentId = "YourDeploymentId";

                Console.WriteLine("Say something...");

                // Starts recognition. It returns when the first utterance has been recognized.
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Checks results.
                if (result.RecognitionStatus != RecognitionStatus.Recognized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"There was an error. Status:{result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, Reason:{result.RecognitionFailureReason}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.RecognizedText}");
                }
            }
        }
        // </recognitionCustomized>

        // <recognitionContinuous>
        // Speech recognition with events
        public static async Task ContinuousRecognitionAsync()
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech factory with specified
            // subscription key and service region. Replace with your own subscription key
            // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("59a0243e86ae4919aa26f9e839f34b28", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input.
            using (var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizer())
            {
                // Subscribes to events.
                recognizer.IntermediateResultReceived += (s, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n    Partial result: {e.Result.RecognizedText}.");
                };

                recognizer.FinalResultReceived += (s, e) => {
                    if (e.Result.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.Recognized)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n    Final result: Status: {e.Result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, Text: {e.Result.RecognizedText}.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n    Final result: Status: {e.Result.RecognitionStatus.ToString()}, FailureReason: {e.Result.RecognitionFailureReason}.");
                    }
                };

                recognizer.RecognitionErrorRaised += (s, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n    An error occurred. Status: {e.Status.ToString()}, FailureReason: {e.FailureReason}");
                };

                recognizer.OnSessionEvent += (s, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n    Session event. Event: {e.EventType.ToString()}.");
                };

                // Starts continuos recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
                Console.WriteLine("Say something...");
                await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
                Console.ReadKey();

                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        // </recognitionContinuous>
    }
}
```

It would also be a good idea to use the [Batch Transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) if you have large amounts of audio.

**UPDATE**

The `SpeechFactory` class was removed lately as a breaking change and replaced with [`SpeechConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig?view=azure-dotnet) as of Speech SDK 1.0.0 as per the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/docs/breaking_changes_1_0_0.md).

> The `SpeechFactory` class is removed. Instead, the class `SpeechConfig` is
>   introduced to describe various settings of speech configuration and
>   the class `AudioConfig` to describe different audio sources (microphone,
>   file, or stream input). To create a `SpeechRecognizer`, use one of its
>   constructors with SpeechConfig and AudioConfig as parameters.

The C# code below shows how to create a SpeechRecognizer using default microphone input.

```
// Creates an instance of speech config with specified subscription key and service region.

var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");

// Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input.
using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
{
    // Performs recognition.
    var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // Process result.
    // ...
}
```

> The same concept is applied for creating `IntentRecognizer` and
>   `TranslationRecognizer`, except that `SpeechTranslationConfig` is
>   required for creating `TranslationRecognizer`.

`CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput()` is replaced by `AudioConfig`. The following C# code shows how to create a speech recognizer using file input.

```
// Creates an instance of speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");

// Creates a speech recognizer using file as audio input.
// Replace with your own audio file name.
using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"whatstheweatherlike.wav"))
{
    using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
    {
        // Performs recognition.
        var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // Process result.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if that is a valid key, but if it is you might want to mask that.

Comment: It is not a valid key.

Comment: Thanks!  Should have tried that in the first place-didn't realize that continuous could be used with file.

Comment: What is that SpeechFactory?

Comment: @JussiPalo It is a class that was used at the time, but it was removed lately and replaced with [`SpeechConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig?view=azure-dotnet) as of Speech SDK 1.0.0 as per the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/docs/breaking_changes_1_0_0.md), thus, I will go ahead and update my answer accordingly, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

As Ali said, StartContinuousRecognitionAsync() and StopContinousRecognitionAsync() is the right way if you want to recognize more than one utterances.

The latest samples for SpeechSDK is available https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk, which includes samples for different languages (curently C++/C#, and will be added if new lanugages are supported) on different platforms (currently Windows/Linux and more platforms will be added).

regarding question 3), the SessionStopped event is used to detect EOF. You can find samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/Windows/csharp_samples/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L194.

Thanks,